# RegEx for matching the last number in vectors of different sizes

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have this string:

```
values="[72, 216, 930],[250],[72],[228, 1539],[12]";
```

am trying to combine two patterns in order to get the last number in first [] type and the number in the second [] type.

```
pattern="\\, ([0-9]+)\\]|\\[([0-9]+)\\]"
```

But it outputs null:

```
930, null, null, 1539, null
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to get from given values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we might not want to bound it from the left, and simply use the `]` from right, then we swipe to left and collect our digits, maybe similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/zC1gKp/1):

```
([0-9]+)\]
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how it would work:

[image]

If you like, we can also bound it from the left, similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/OBQNnb/1):

```
([\[\s,])([0-9]+)(\])
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the second one would work:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = ", ([0-9]+)]";
final String string = "[72, 216, 930],[250],[72],[228, 1539],[12]";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Full match: , 930]
Group 1: 930
Full match: , 1539]
Group 1: 1539
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package Sample;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StackOverFlow{


    final static String regex = "\\d*]";
    final static String string = "[72, 216, 930],[250],[72],[228, 1539],[12]";

    final static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final static Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String val = matcher.group(0).replace("]", "");
            System.out.println(val);
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
930
250
72
1539
12
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the data is actually in between square brackets, you could use a capturing group, start the match with `[` and end the match with `]`

```
\[(?:\d+,\h+)*(\d+)]
```

In Java

```
\\[(?:\\d+,\\h+)*(\\d+)]
```

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(?:\d+,\h+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching 1+ digit, comma and 1+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(\d+)` Capture in group 1 matching 1+ digit
- `]` Match closing square bracket

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bsHk8a/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ImOcdi)

For example:

```
String regex = "\\[(?:\\d+,\\h+)*(\\d+)]";
String string = "[72, 216, 930],[250],[72],[228, 1539],[12]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Result:

```
930
250
72
1539
12
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for a structure such as this, it's likely beneficial to parse the whole thing into memory, then index into the elements you're particularly interested in to your heart's content. Should the structure change unexpectedly/dynamically, you won't need to rewrite your regex, just index as needed as many times as you wish:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String values = "[72, 216, 930],[250],[72],[228, 1539],[12]";

        String[] data = values.substring(1, values.length() - 1).split("\\]\\s*,\\s*\\[");
        ArrayList<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String d : data) {
            result.add(d.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        }

        System.out.println(result.get(0)[result.get(0).length-1]); // => 930
        System.out.println(result.get(1)[0]);                      // => 250
    }
}
```